# Safe sharing of npm components built with different graphics frameworks vuetify/quasar

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-component, vuetify.js, quasar

We have some large applications built with vuetify. Now we are developing new apps in Quasar. We have an internal npm server and would like to share components between applications with npm packages. Since apps could be either vuetify or quasar and the same would be for shared components, our concern is whether this approach of mixing frameworks could work. I'm aware that npm somewhat "flattens" the underling framework but i'm not sure about possible conflicts like for instance on css classes.

Thanks for your hints